# OnSelectedIndexChanged and AutoPostBack

Tags: javascript, session, timer

I found some javascript code on here that will display a session timeout warning and a message to inform the user that they have been logged out (as shown below) However my issue with this code is that if the user is not in front of the computer to click the ok button on either one of the alerts no further action is taken. So at the moment the timeout warning is set to be displayed 1 minute before the redirect, when that warning pops up the timer is halted until the user clicks the button and the second message pops up 1 minute after the user clicks the ok button then the redirect doesn't happen until the user clicks the button on that warning. The biggest of the issues here for me is that obviously the actual session timer is completely separate to these javascript timers so if the user is not in front of the screen when the first warning message pops up saying they have a minute before the session expires and that minute passes, then they see the message and click ok, they have not been redirected and will think they have one minute left but the session has already expired and I have code in each page the timer runs on so that they redirect to the index page if the timer has expired and all of the session variables stored are gone so they click on something and will be redirected anyway.

Is there a better way to do this? Can I use the javascript to poll the session state and find out how much time is actually remaining rather than running a completely separated timer?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var iddleTimeoutWarning = null;
    var iddleTimeout = null;

    function pageLoad() {

        if (iddleTimeoutWarning != null)
            clearTimeout(iddleTimeoutWarning);
        if (iddleTimeout != null)
            clearTimeout(iddleTimeout);

        var millisecTimeOutWarning = <%= int.Parse(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SessionTimeoutWarning"]) * 60 * 1000 %>;
        var millisecTimeOut = <%= int.Parse(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SessionTimeout"]) * 60 * 1000 %>;

        iddleTimeoutWarning = setTimeout("DisplayIddleWarning()", millisecTimeOutWarning);
        iddleTimeout = setTimeout("TimeoutPage()", millisecTimeOut);
    }

    function DisplayIddleWarning() {
        alert("Your session will expire in one minute due to inactivity.");
    }

    function TimeoutPage() {
        alert("Your session has expired due to inactivity.");
        location.replace("index.aspx");
    }

</script>
```

Thanks.

Comment: `alert` blocks the UI and any further script execution. So just use some other form of dialog, f.e. the ones that jQuery.ui provides …

Comment: That did the trick. If you want the rep add your comment as an answer and I will mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`alert` blocks the UI and any further script execution.

So just use some other form of dialog, f.e. the ones that [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) provides.